# how to show the lists based on the switch case in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, switch-statement

I need to show the dropdown lists based on the selected value from the first dropdown

**.constant.ts**

```
export const recordConstant = {
    memberContact: 'Member Contact',
    about: 'About',
    other: 'Other',
    standarActions:'Standard Actions',
  gymSignUp: 'Gym Sign Up',
    gymVisits: 'Gym Visits'
    }
```

**.component.ts**

```
export class RecordComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

 public recordConstant= RecordConstant;

public memberContactCodes: LookupActionCode[];
  public memberContactCodes: LookupActionCode[];
  public otherCodes: LookupActionCode[];
  public standardActionCodes: LookupActionCode[];
  public aboutCodes: LookupActionCode[];


ngOninit(){
}
public getMemberContactActionCodes() {
    let baseUrl = `/endpoint`;
    this._restfulService
      .restfulGetData(baseUrl)
     .subscribe(
        (actionLookupData: ActionLookupData) => {
          if (actionLookupData) {
            this.memberContactCodes = actionLookupData.MemberContactCodes;
           this.otherCodes = actionLookupData.OtherActionCodes;
            this.standardActionCodes = actionLookupData.StandardActionCodes;
            this.aboutCodes = actionLookupData.BillingActionCodes;
            }
       
}

public setActionList(){
 //let  Lists
  //let ActionLists = LookupActionCode[this.Name]
  let Lists:any =''
  switch(this.actionType){
    case ActionRecordConstant.memberContact:
      Lists = this.memberContactCodes;
      break;
      case RecordConstant.referral:
      Lists = this.aboutCodes;
      break;
      case RecordConstant.other:
      Lists = this.otherCodes;
      break;
      case Constant.standardActions:
      Lists = this.standardActionCodes;
      break;
case: Constant.gymSignUp:
Lists = ///
break;
  }
  return Lists;

}
```

**.component.html**

```
<label for="action" class="cpp-required"> <b>Category</b></label>
<select class="form-control" required (change) ="setActionList()">
                <option value="" disabled [selected]="true"></option>
             
                <option [value] = "recordConstant.about">
                 {{actionRecordConstant.about}}
                </option>
                <option [value] ="recordConstant.memberContact">
                  {{actionRecordConstant.memberContact}}
                 </option>
                 <option [value]="recordConstant.other" >
                  {{actionRecordConstant.other}}
                 </option>
                 <option [value] ="recordConstant.standActions">
                  {{actionRecordConstant.billing}}
                 </option>
        </select>
 <label for="action" class="cpp-required"> <b>Lists</b></label>
 <select class="form-control">
                <option value="" disabled [selected]="true"></option>
               <option *ngFor="let actionlist of Lists"
                  [value] ="actionlist.Name"> {{actionlist.Name}}</option></select>
```

From the above based on the selection of Category Ihaveto change the lists
I have tried the above code but not showing the lists based on the first dropdown selection

Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, not sure this is what you expect.

**.component.html**

```
 <label for="optionsList" class="cpp-required"> <b>Category</b></label>
 <select class="form-control" required (change)="setActionList($event.target.value)">
   <option value="" disabled [selected]="true"></option>
   <option *ngFor="let action of optionsList"
           [value]="action"> {{action}}</option>
 </select>
 <label for="anotherOptionList" class="cpp-required"> <b>Lists</b></label>
 <select class="form-control">
   <option value="" disabled [selected]="true"></option>
   <option *ngFor="let anotherOption of anotherOptionList"
           [value]="anotherOption"> {{anotherOption}}</option>
 </select>
```

**.component.ts**

```
 optionsList: string[] = ['Member Contact', 'About', 'Other', 'Standard Actions'];
 anotherOptionList: LookupActionCode[] = [];

 setActionList(actionType: any): void {
   this.anotherOptionList = [];
   switch (actionType) {
     case 'Member Contact':
       this.anotherOptionList = this.memberContactCodes;
       break;
     case 'About':
       this.anotherOptionList = this.aboutCodes;
       break;
     case 'Other':
       this.anotherOptionList = this.otherCodes;
       break;
     case 'Standard Actions':
       this.anotherOptionList = this.standardActionCodes;
       break;
     default:
       this.anotherOptionList = [];
   }
 }
```

Comment: thanks@paranaan, but I need to use the switch case to provide the lists based on the selection so could you please check my code if there is any mistakes and help me on the same

Comment: You can change logic in `setActionList(actionType: any): void` to set new options to `this.anotherOptionList`.

The select `anotherOptionList`  in `HTML` will listen to any change that happen to `this.anotherOptionList`

Comment: thanks@paranaaan, could you please edit my switch case code then it willbe helpful for me

Comment: I'm already edited.